# Transformation of positive semi-definite matrices

Tags: matrices, determinant, positive-definite

Let $a,b,c,d,e$ be positive reals such that the following matrix is positive semi-definite:
$$
\begin{pmatrix} a+4b+6c+4d+e & a+3b+3c+d & a+2b+c \\ 
a+3b+3c+d & a+2b+c & a+b  \\ 
a+2b+c & a+b & a \\ \end{pmatrix}
$$

Does it follow that also the following matrix is positive semi-definite?
$$
\begin{pmatrix} e & d & c \\ 
d & c & b  \\ 
c & b & a \\ \end{pmatrix}
$$

[By iterated subtraction of rows and columns, the two matrices have the same determinant; but do these operations preserve also this stronger property?]

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} a+4b+6c+4d+e & a+3b+3c+d & a + 2b+c \\a+3b+3c+d & a+2b+c & a+b \\ a+2b+c & a+b & a\end{pmatrix}, \quad
B = \begin{pmatrix} e & d & c \\ d & c & b \\ c & b & a \end{pmatrix}.$$

Then $A=UBU^T$ and $B=VAV^T$, where

$$U = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, \quad 
V = U^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -2 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} $$

Therefore $A$ and $B$ represent the same quadratic form, but in different bases,  hence $A$ is positive semi-definite if and only if $B$ is positive semi-definite.

Added to answer: $x^TBx = (V^Tx)^TA(V^Tx) \geq 0$, hence $B$ is positive semi-definite.

Comment: The result generalizes to higher order matrices of those forms -- the rows of $U$ are the rows of the Pascal triangle.

Answer (score -1):

Edit: I make a rectification of an erroneous extension to semi-definite matrices (following remarks of @Paolo Leonetti).

I will consider only the particular case of positive definite matrices according to Sylvester criterion (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix). 
This criteria is applied by checking the positivity of  determinants of "russian dolls matrices" beginning

- by the North-West corner $M(1,1), M(1:2,1:2)$ and $M(1:3,1:3)=M$, or
- by the South-East corner $M(3,3), M(2:3,2:3)$ and $M(1:3,1:3)=M$.

It is this latter criteria that we will consider.

$$A=\begin{pmatrix} a+4b+6c+4d+e & a+3b+3c+d & a+2b+c \\ 
a+3b+3c+d & a+2b+c & a+b  \\ 
a+2b+c & a+b & a \\ \end{pmatrix} \ \ \text{and} \ \ B=\begin{pmatrix} e & d & c \\ 
d & c & b  \\ 
c & b & a \\ \end{pmatrix}$$

Let $M_{23}=M(2:3,2:3)$ (we keep in a matrix $M$ the elements which are in column 2 and 3, i.e., we suppress line 1 and column 1).

Thus it suffices to check the equivalence:

$$det(A)>0 \ \& \ det(A_{23})> 0 \ \& \ a > 0  \ \ \Longleftrightarrow \ \ det(B)\geq0 \ \& \ det(B_{23})\geq 0 \ \& \ a \geq 0 \ \ \ (1)$$

But $det(A)=det(B)$ (you say it in your text), and one can verify that:

$$det(A_{23})=det(B_{23})=ac-b^2$$

Thus (1) is established.

Remark: coefficients $1,2,1$, then $1,3,3,1$, then $1,4,6,4,1$ that appear in matrix $A$ come from Pascal triangle. This remark could open the way to a new theorem and new proof, generalizable to larger matrices of this form.

Comment: Where did you take such version of Sylvester criterion about *positive semi-definite* matrices? I believe too the answer is affirmative, but shouldn't we check *all* principal minors of $A$ and $B$? ..

Comment: No, only the **leading principal minors** are to be checked, as explicitly said in the article of wikipedia I have cited. Here are their terms "The kth leading principal minor of a matrix M is the determinant of its upper-left k by k sub-matrix. It turns out that a matrix is positive definite if and only if all these determinants are positive".

Comment: Indeed, here we are *not* talking about positive definite matrices.

Comment: What is the nature of my misunderstanding ? Do you mean positive **semi**-definiteness versus $definiteness$ (without the "semi") ? or is it the positivity of coefficients you are meaning ?

Comment: A matrix $M$ is positive semi-definite if $x^TMx$ is nonnegative for each vector $x$. On the other hand, positive definiteness require strictly positiveness. The version of Sylvester criterion which you are talking about is about the latter case. Of course, there are variants of such criterion also for PSD matrices, but probably your condition is not sufficient. [I am just aware of a version requiring to check all principal minors, which is not quoted in Wikipedia]

Comment: In my view, results that are valuable for positive definite matrices are in general extendable by a limit process to results for semi-definite matrices, with adaptations of course. Here in the case of your result, the equivalence I give could be written at first with strict equalities $>0$ and then passed to the limit to get inequalities $\geq0$.

Comment: Which limit are you talking about? Consider the matrix X=[1,2,2; 2,1,1; 2,1,1]. Then the determinants of $X_{123}$, $X_{23}$ and $X_3$ are nonnegative. But $X$ is not PSD.

Comment: I agree. I will have a closer look now... Thank you.